# why and how instance variable get initialized without getting initialized by constructor in Java?

Tags: java, object, instance-variables

```
public class Test{
int i;
Test(){
    System.out.println(i);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test obj=new Test();
    }
}
```

Output=0

**P.S**: I am naive in Java so this question could be very silly. I am expecting your support. Thanks

Comment: That's how Java is *defined*. Read the JLR -- the Java Language Reference -- for the details.

Comment: The default value of an int is 0

Comment: When you declare an int as a "field" (class variable), It initialize automatically with value "0", but when belongs to other method, is "null"

Comment: @Abdelhak Instance variable belongs to Object and static variable belongs to class. In the above case variable i belongs to whom since there is no object and i is not a static variable.

Comment: Are you sure this program has any output?  I would not expect it to.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for pointing out that, one line in main method was missed by mistake. I corrected that and also got the answer of my earlier question but that leads to another problem. I have provided second edit regarding new problem. Please review that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static/Instance fields which are not initialized will be set to a default value by the compiler.

The table bellow indicates the default value for data types:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
|        Data Type         | Default Value (for fields) |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| byte                     | 0                          |
| short                    | 0                          |
| int                      | 0                          |
| long                     | 0L                         |
| float                    | 0.0f                       |
| double                   | 0.0d                       |
| char                     | '\u0000'                   |
| String (or any object)   | null                       |
| boolean                  | false                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

For more information, you can see the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

See, every `Instance-Variable or Class-Variable` initialized by it's [default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> In case instance-variable is some Reference type then it will be
>   always assigned with it's default value by `null`

So, here in your case `int` is primitive type whose `default` value is `0(zero)` that's the reason you get `0` in out-put.